# PHPStan: Property with generic class does not specify its types: TKey, T

Tags: generics, doctrine, static-analysis, phpdoc, phpstan

I'm running **PHPStan** on a **Symfony** project where I have the following relation in a **Doctrine** entity:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Course\Slide", mappedBy="chapter", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"listOrder" = "ASC"})
 *
 * @var ArrayCollection<Slide>
 */
private $slides;
```

Running analysis with **rule level 6** I got the following message about the property (and its getter return type):

> Property `App\Entity\Course\Chapter::$slides` with generic class `Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection` does not specify its types: TKey, T
>             You can turn this off by setting `checkGenericClassInNonGenericObjectType: false` in your `phpstan.neon`.

My edit attempts only confused PHPStan, maybe because I'm not fully understanding generics here. But silencing the message just because I don't get it would be stupid.

What am I supposed to add or change in the PHPDoc ?

Comment: Please ask on GitHub next time: https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan/issues/new/choose

Comment: @OndřejMirtes I didn't want to bother you on GitHub as it is not a bug, but I'll remember (I often visit your GitHub btw).

Comment: I treat GitHub issues as a support inbox, so it's fine :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`ArrayCollection` has two type variables: TKey and T. So `ArrayCollection<Slide>` isn't sufficient, you need something like `ArrayCollection<int, Slide>`.

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand, but just to be sure: the `int` type represents the foreign key type ?

Comment: I'm not sure what Doctrine puts there as the iterable key type, you should try it out.

Comment: Don't forget the space between coma and Slide! I lost one hour because of this space ^^

Answer (score 6):

It's

```php
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection<int, Slide>
 */
```

Doing `dump()` on the parent entity shows that `$slides` is a 0-indexed array:

```
0 => App\Entity\Slide
1 => App\Entity\Slide
```

So it's an `int`, but not the entity's ID (since it isn't persisted yet).

Here's an in-depth article on generics by Ondřej Mirtes (=author of PhpStan): https://medium.com/@ondrejmirtes/generics-in-php-using-phpdocs-14e7301953

Comment: Thank you, I get it now. I have tried to read this post in the past but did not understand, now it clicks ! Going to refactor some code with generics